# Show recently used branches

Tags: magit

In git I run this command to show recently used branches:

`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --count=10 refs/heads`

How do I do this in magit?

Answer (score 1):

This currently isn't possible in Magit. If you open a feature request, then I will consider adding such a feature, but I cannot promise that we will do so or even that we will do so soon.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there is the option `magit-list-refs-sortby`:

> Any value accepted by the `--sort' flag of` git for-each-ref' can
> be used.  For example, "-creatordate" places refs with more
> recent committer or tagger dates earlier in the list.  A list of
> strings can also be given in order to pass multiple sort keys to
> `git for-each-ref'.

Answer (score 1):

I too wanted something like my personal `git mru` alias (shows
the 20 most recent branches that I have used) in my magit status
buffers.

After some tinkering, copying from magit source, and reading the
docs, I came up with the following (you may want to rename the
functions as you see fit):

```lisp
;; like magit-refs--format-local-branches, but only for the 20 most recent
;; branches, sorted by committerdate
(defun my/magit-refs--format-recent-local-branches ()
  (let ((lines (-keep #'magit-refs--format-local-branch
                      (magit-git-lines
                       "for-each-ref"
                       "--sort=-committerdate"
                       "--count=20"
                       (concat "--format=\
%(HEAD)%00%(refname:short)%00%(refname)%00\
%(upstream:short)%00%(upstream)%00%(upstream:track)%00"
                               (if magit-refs-show-push-remote "\
%(push:remotename)%00%(push)%00%(push:track)%00%(subject)"
                                 "%00%00%00%(subject)"))
                       "refs/heads"
                       magit-buffer-arguments))))
    (unless (magit-get-current-branch)
      (push (magit-refs--format-local-branch
             (concat "*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" (magit-rev-format "%s")))
            lines))
    (setq-local magit-refs-primary-column-width
                (let ((def (default-value 'magit-refs-primary-column-width)))
                  (if (atom def)
                      def
                    (pcase-let ((`(,min . ,max) def))
                      (min max (apply #'max min (mapcar #'car lines)))))))
    (mapcar (pcase-lambda (`(,_ ,branch ,focus ,branch-desc ,u:ahead ,p:ahead
                                ,u:behind ,upstream ,p:behind ,push ,msg))
              (list branch focus branch-desc u:ahead p:ahead
                    (make-string (max 1 (- magit-refs-primary-column-width
                                           (length (concat branch-desc
                                                           u:ahead
                                                           p:ahead
                                                           u:behind))))
                                 ?\s)
                    u:behind upstream p:behind push
                    msg))
            lines)))

;; like magit-insert-local-branches, but only for a few of the most recent
;; branches. 
(defun my/magit-insert-recent-local-branches ()
  "Insert section showing the most recently used local branches."
  (magit-insert-section (local nil)
    (magit-insert-heading "Recent Branches:")
    (dolist (line (my/magit-refs--format-recent-local-branches))
      (pcase-let ((`(,branch . ,strings) line))
        (magit-insert-section
          ((eval (if branch 'branch 'commit))
           (or branch (magit-rev-parse "HEAD"))
           t)
          (apply #'magit-insert-heading strings)
          (when (magit-buffer-margin-p)
            (magit-refs--format-margin branch))
          (magit-refs--insert-cherry-commits branch))))
    (insert ?\n)
    (magit-make-margin-overlay nil t)))

;; add a list of the most recently used branches to the bottom of magit
;; status buffers
(magit-add-section-hook
 'magit-status-sections-hook
 'my/magit-insert-recent-local-branches
 'magit-insert-unpulled-from-upstream ;; this is the section that we want to show the branches below.
)
```

The following docs were helpful here:

https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Status-Sections

https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Section-Hooks

https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#References-Buffer